# In boost log keyword::rotation_size ,when adding new lines how to delete the first line

Tags: c++, boost

What I do:

1.I added log file to my c++ code with reference to the link http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_file.cpp.

2.The log file is generated ,and when it reach the maximum rotation_size ,the whole line deleted and started from first.

What I need to do:

1.I need to add log in to the log file ,so that if I add 1000 lines (which reaches maximum rotation_size).when I add the next line (1001th line), I don't want to clear all the 1000 lines added before.I want to delete only the first line and want the latest 1000 lines.

How to do that?

Comment: So you want a circular log buffer? If so, then write a log class that will do that - wrap around at 1000 lines and start overwriting the first ones. A :std::vector would do, so would a std::array and a number of other classes. But *you* need to manage the wrap-around/circular logic. It's not rocket sience though; fairly simple to implement - just wrap your writing offset at 1000 lines back to the beginning.

Comment: @jesper Thanks for the reply.Can you suggest any link.ilike to do it with boost log.ya you areare right I need circular log buffer.

Comment: @Eichhornchen Thanks for the reply.Ya you are right ,no need of opencv tag here.I removed it.I need circular buffer log using boost log

Comment: Why the insistance on boost::log?

Comment: @jesper  I am working in opencv project,I already used boost in the project .so I insisit boost::log.

Comment: or else please suggest any efficicient circular buffer log